# What is this green paste on cold water outlet

Tags: plumbing, water, sink

Does anyone know what this green stuff is [image: here]

It has a paste like consistency.

Pretty sure that is isn’t oxidised copper as there it is too thick/ there is too much and none is on the copper pipework.

If anymore information is required let me know.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/86004/green-and-white-stuff-on-copper-pipes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Green and white stuff on copper pipes](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/86004/green-and-white-stuff-on-copper-pipes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The green stuff is cupric chloride, a byproduct of corrosion of the valve body. It's typical of water leakage where the water is of low pH. It's usually found on copper pipes. Your pipes have been painted so it's not forming on them but you do have untreated copper going into the valve. Make sure all the connection are tight.

Comment: There are unpainted stretches of the copper pipework that have no discloration, is it likely to all be internal to the pipe and only visible at the joints? If so, as this leads to my kitchen tap, is the water from these pipes still safe to drink?

Comment: It's totally safe to drink the water from all the pipes.  Your painted pipes are not the norm, most are not painted.  It won't be internal to the pipes. It was probably caused by a droplet of water that seeped  through before sealing completely and it's on the outside of the valve, not the inside.

Comment: Accumulation of condensation can aid in this happening too.

Comment: So just clean it off and alls good? If you look at the image, theres is also some on the plastic coupling, so is it possible the pipes were compromised prior to being installed and some rubbed off?

Comment: @123  Yep, clean it off  and all's good. Keep in mind, as Jack pointed out in his comment, that condensation can cause this too. The pipes could have had some of it when installed but "compromise" is way to harsh....  I have all over some of my pipes and have never cleaned them off.

Comment: @JACK Cheers for the help. After some more research I believe it may be similar to this https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/104922/green-residue-on-the-joints-of-copper-water-pipes. As it is a new build though and the worst affected parts are the joints, I think possibly the plumbers didn’t clean off the flux properly and then just covered up the issue with paint. Sound like a possibility?

Comment: @123  The plumber definitely cleaned off those joints. They are very smooth without any solder globs hanging from them.  It's easy to clean the joints, just wipe them with a rag while the joint is hot. Whoever painted the pipes did a good job and it would have taken the plumber a lot longer to paint them than go back and clean off the flux.  The example you compared it to had active water dripping and that's where the green came from.  your guys did a nice job, enjoy it.

Comment: @JACK Fair enough, not much experience with plumbing (as is probably obvious), so was just double checking there couldn’t be any potential future issues. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance it is the glue (or cleaner) used for PVC pipes. There may have been PVC pipes previously installed and it dripped there. The part might be secondhand also, quite common with fittings. But it should be dry if glue, not paste.